# How to define function different in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I want to define function in Mathematica on different way. 
Actually, if I already have functions a and b. How can I print
the value in some point of function f but without defining functions
a and b like f. I dont want to use this before a[x_]:=...,  b[x_]:=...
because a and b I obtained different and I can not change everything above
in my code because of this.

```
  a = x;
  b = 2*x;

  f[x_] := a + b; 
  f[2]
```

Comment: The output from this is `3 x`. Isn't this what you want? It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want value of function in point 2, I need f[2], but I got the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html), like this:

```
a = x
b = 2*x

f[x_] = a + b
f[2]
```

Be sure to [read the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) on this to understand the implications of using one or the other.

Comment: @Szabolics Thanks, I will. I must put stronger question because of negative points.